# SAS import wizard is throwing "ERROR: Failed to connect to server"

Tags: sas, import-from-excel

I have PC SAS 64 bit and Office 2013 32 bit installed on my Windows machine. I am trying to use the import wizard and it gives me

> ERROR: Failed to connect to server.

Can anyone help me to sort this out?

I have selected `Microsoft Excel Workbook on PC Files Server` rather than `Microsoft Excel Workbook (*.xls *.xlsb...)` as "Standard data source".

Comment: So do you have PC Files Server running? And does your PC know how to connect to it?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem when tried to import file that was in use by another user.
Copy the file with different name or location and try to run import again.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check with a sas program and try to change the engine :

Like

```
/* import */
PROC IMPORT
    DATAFILE="c:\test.xlsx"
    OUT=WORK.TEST
    DBMS=XLSX REPLACE;
    RANGE="Sheet1$A1:G";
    GETNAMES=YES;
RUN;
```

Try with DBMS=excelcs or DBMS=XLSX or DBMS=excel,
with the extension from *.xslx to *.xls
and check correct pathname.